# Iterating over table cells

Tags: javascript, html

So I have this code (from the gracious help from this site!)

```
window.onload = function inventorytable() {
var tableRows = document.getElementById

("inventorytable").getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].getElementsByTagName("tr");
```

Now from here, I want to get all of the TDs, under all of the TRs. I also want to be able to perform operations on the TDs, depending on which TD (i.e. which column) they are in the table.

So for example, if I have

```
<tr>
<th>Processor Speed</th>
<th>Amount of RAM</th>
<tr>
<td>2.0</td>
<td>3.0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3.2</td>
<td>4.0</td>
</tr>
```

I want to be able to select each TD separately, depending on its order within the TR, and then add text to it. There will be a variable number of TRs, at least 20, and possibly more. There are going to be about 10-15 TDs.

The text added would be something like " Ghz" or " GB"

Comment: jQuery could really simplify your logic. Are you opposed to using it?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Don't know how to the get the `td`s? How to iterate over a collection of elements? How to add text to elements?

Comment: I am opposed to using jQuery unless it really is necessary. I am attempting to teach myself how to use Javascript.

I am stuck in how I should select the multiple TDs under the TRs.

Comment: All of the current answers are quite heavy. I recommend to use the `.rows` and `.cells` properties to access an individual cell, eg: `table.rows[0].cells[0]` (which returns the first cell of the first row, because these sets are zero-based).

Comment: I admire the desire to learn Javascript without leaning on jquery, but at a certain point you're cutting off your nose to spite your face. If you're opposed to jquery on the basis of bloat, there are a number of smaller libraries that make selecting elements trivial.

Comment: @Derek One should first learn JavaScript, *then* jQuery. If one understand the principles of JavaScript, learning jQuery is easy. The reverse, however...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to [iterate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) over all `tr` elements (which is a [`NodeList` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/NodeList), returned from [`getElementsByTagName` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName)):

```
for(var i = 0, l = tableRows.length; i < l; i++) {
    var row = tableRows[i];
    //...
}
```

Inside the loop you can get all `td`s of one row again with `getElementsByTagName` or using the [`.cells` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLTableRowElement) property. You can then decide to either iterate over them as well or to access the specific cells explicitly, such as `cells[1]` to access the second cell (second column) in that row.

If the cells contain simple text or you don't have any event handlers bound to their descendants, you can simply use [`innerHTML` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.innerHTML) to change the element's text content.

Otherwise you have to [create a new text node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM%3adocument.createTextNode) and [append it](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.appendChild) to the cell (that might be the best option in any case).

---

The [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) is a great source for all kinds of information, including the DOM and JavaScript.

Comment: Would it look like this:

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function inventorytable() {
var tableRows = document.getElementById

("inventorytable").getElementsByTagName("tbody")

[0].getElementsByTagName("tr");

for(var i = 0, l = trs.length; i < l; i++) {
 tds = tableRows.getElementsByTagName("td");
 var processor = tds[8].innerHTML
 var ram = tds[9].innerHTML
 var rspeed = tds[11].innerHTML
 processor = processor + " Ghz"
 ram = ram + " GB"
 rspeed = rspeed + " Mhz"
 

}}
</script>

Comment: If you fix the variable names, then yes. If you want to add the text to the element you'd also have to assign it back to `innerHTML`. For example with the `+=` operator: `tds[11].innerHTML += ' GHz'`. And never forget to declare your variables with `var`!

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it:

```
var table = document.getElementById( 'inventorytable' );

[].forEach.call( table.rows, function ( row, i ) {
    [].forEach.call( row.cells, function ( cell, j ) {

        // this function runs for every cell in the table
        cell // references the current cell
        row // references the current row (the row the cell is in)
        i // the row index (0 = first row, 1 = second row, etc.)
        j // the cell index (0 = first cell in row, 1 = second cell in row, etc.)

    });
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/6tXUm/

Note: You need to include [ES5 shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim/blob/master/es5-shim.js) since some older browsers (mainly IE8) don't implement the new ES5 features like `forEach`.

Comment: forEach doesn't exist in IE7 or IE8, which means it isn't a truly cross-browser solution.

Comment: @Akkuma `forEach` was introduced in EcmaScript 5 (the latest version of JavaScript). IE8 is not "ES5-ready", but that's not a problem. There is an [ES5 shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim/blob/master/es5-shim.js) which implements the new ES5 features for non-ready browsers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simplify your life and logic here is an example of what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/Akkuma/2wJ8G/

What I'm doing is first getting the exact table and from there grabbing all td elements. It will automatically run through each one in order of row, as that is their order in the markup. You don't need to first select `document.getElementsByTagName('tr')`. If you need to filter you can look up the tree or select elements at a higher level first, for instance the `thead`.

In the second example, I know explicitly there is only one tbody and can access the area, which is of length 1, and chain `.getElementsByTagName('td')` to get only those `td` within the tbody (you could have a td in your `thead` or `tfoot`)

The third example uses @Rob W 's recommendation of using table dom traversal. At least in my example using it only complicated the code.

The final example combines Rob W's recommendation (ex3) with ex2. This allows you to skip having to write two loops.